# Error on unmarshaling with generated code (moxy): "A descriptor with default root element ... was not found in the project"

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

I generated code using moxy for different xsd-Files:
http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/generalinvoiceresponse_400.xsd
and
http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xmlstandards_generelle_rechnung_beispiele_antwort_4.3_20100901.zip

I generated jaxb-classes for both xsd (using moxy). Then i tried unmarshal xml-files (genrated by eclipse) with this code:

```
public void tempTest() throws JAXBException{
    JAXBContext jC = JAXBContext.newInstance(<package for corresponding type>.ResponseType.class);
    jC.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(ResponseTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/responses/generalInvoiceResponse_400.xml"));
}
```

With xml-File of 4.3-type (2nd link) this works fine but with xml of 400-type (1st link) i get this error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25008] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor with default root element {http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/de}response was not found in the project]
```

It seems to be a problem with the name-space. The name space is different but i can not see a relevant difference in generated code or generated xml - the name space is consistent.
so what could cause this problem (where is the difference) and how to solve it?

**small addition:** i also tried to unmarshal xml marshaled with jaxb/moxy-code:

```
public void marshall() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
    JAXBContext jC = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseType.class);
    ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
    jC.createMarshaller().marshal( of.createResponse(of.createResponseType()),new FileOutputStream("simpleresponse.xml"));
}
```

this creates an very simple xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/de"/>
```

unmarshaling this yields the **same error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a `JAXBContext` based on a model generated from an XML Schema you should always use the the `newInstance` method that takes the package name.  This will ensure that all the necessary bits are processed.

```
JAXBContext jC = JAXBContext.newInstance("ch.forum_datenaustausch.de");
```

When you use the `JAXBContext.newInstance(Class...)` method the JAXB implementation is assuming that you started from Jav classes.  Since the role of `ObjectFactory` can be played by any class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` the `ObjectFactory` class generated from the XML schema will be automatically picked up.  You could do the following, but I still recommend the above approach:

```
JAXBContext jC = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResponseType.class, ObjectFactory.class);
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Thank you! but could you probably explain why it is working with one
>   xsd and not with the other?

The schema where it "works" may have a global element with an anonymous type which causes an `@XmlRootElement` annotation to be generated meaning the `ObjectFactory` is not required.  The other may have a global element with a named complex type which causes an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on an `ObjectFactory` class to be generated.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Thank you! but could you probably explain why it is working with one xsd and not with the other?

Comment: @dermoritz - I have updated my answer with a possible explanation.

Comment: that was the first thing i did: look at the generated code, but both "ResponseType"-classes have same annotations "@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)" and "@XmlType(name = "responseType", propOrder = {...". but anyway it is working now :-)

Comment: @dermoritz - I have just done a trivial edit, feel free to undo the down vote if you wish.

Comment: i didn't down vote, i only checked if i upvoted: by clicking on upvote, the upvote is cancled, then i clicked again upvote. (the upvote triangle is orange for me) - without my upvote the score would be -1.

Comment: This is spot on my problem. I didn't specify my jaxb lib version in my pom.xml for my generated code. 2 years later, I regenerate my code, the newest version of Jaxb kicks in and my code gives me this cryptic error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error message over WebLogic 12 but problem was due to namespace prefix. 
It got fixed after explicitly adding name space in @Xmlrootelement(name="namespace:root tag name")